# Manipulating large images on a Canvas to maintain aspect ratios results in outofmemory issues

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to load a background image for a game as well as some smaller images, placing them on a Canvas, and letting people interact with the smaller overlayed images (like move, rotate)

In order to maintain aspect ratio (e.g. 5:3) I tried loading in the images as a bitmap and resizing them myself.  The idea was to do cropping/letter-boxing for the background according to the canvas's width/height, and maintain the correct ratio of size for the smaller images.

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceImg);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg2, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

In order to cater for tablets/phones i have a background PNG background image at 1600x1000 and 200kb.

However I am now struggling with out of memory issues due to the bitmap being 1600x1000x4byte=6.4 mb of ram and more when it tries to resize.
(I am using the emulator at the moment when these issues occur)

I decided to change it to use canvas.setBackgroundResource

```
    SceneCanvas sceneCanvas = (SceneCanvas) findViewById(R.id.the_canvas);
    sceneCanvas.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_scene_1600x900);
```

This works well, except it fills the screen and does not maintain aspect ratio.

Is there a way to set the background maintaining aspect ratio?  Or have I just gone down the wrong route completely and should use ImageViews and render to the canvas somehow to avoid OutOfMemory issues

Answer (score 1):

Given that Java code is only allowed a heap size of around 20MB or so, you’re always going to have trouble with large bitmaps (unless you resort to native code in C/C++/etc).

One option is to use a [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to load your image, and in the [Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) you can specify an inSampleSize to downsample the image as it’s being read in. This should avoid chewing up memory by trying to load the entire original image. There is even an inJustDecodeBounds option, so your code can check the dimensions of the image, instead of having them hard-wired into the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the memory limit on Android is somewhere between 16 - 24 MB memory (depending on device).  This is regardless of whether the device has a lot more memory.  Also, the memory used by Bitmaps is included in the limit, resulting in lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.  After some searching, there are 3 options I could find:

- Allocate memory from native code using the NDK (native development kit) and JNI
- For images one can also use OpenGL textures, the texture memory is not counted towards the limit.
- take advantage of certain bitmap options to reduce size; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

To see how much memory your app has  allocated one  can use, android.os.Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize().